# EF Core 6: Query computed property

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core

I (graphql) would like to query the computed property `IsOpen` with EF Core 6.

```cs
public class MyEntity
{
    public Status Status { get; set; }
    public bool IsOpen => Status is Status.Open or Status.InProgress or Status.Dispatched;
}
```

When I just try it like that I get the `could not be translated` error.

The only workaround I know is to persist the property with an empty setter to the DB like:

```cs
public bool IsOpen 
{
    get => Status is Status.Open or Status.InProgress or Status.Dispatched;
    private set {}
}
```

While this works it's not ideal because a change in this code would not update all already existing DB entries.

**Edit**: The UI needs filtering and sorting based on this `IsOpen` property. After some thinking I'm afraid there is no way around persisting the column. I see now way how EF Core or plain SQL could otherwise *order* the result.

Comment: Show your query. Why not write `Select` with this property?

Comment: Or make it a computed column in the database and map it to your entity as getter-only property and `ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate()`.

Comment: You have 2 options to use here, 1 - Write the `IsOpen` logic part of the `Select`. 2 - Write the property so it is L2E Compliant, so it can be translated to SQL and run on the DB Engine. There is a library on github (https://github.com/axelheer/nein-linq) which does something similar.

Comment: Can't really show the query as this is build by hotchocolate graphql. Some where and order on the IsOpen property. It just operates on the IQueryable<MyEntity>.

Comment: Well, how do you feed hotchocolate? With which query?